# NodeJS with mongoose: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is the story: new to NodeJS > trying to seed a mongoDB database using mongoose > need help.

I have two collections: Users (or players) and Teams.
Seed goal: to create some Users and then create some Teams, populated with some of those Users.

Here is my User schema:

```
var mongoose                = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose   = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    username: String,
    password: String
});
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Here is my Team schema:

```
var mongoose                = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose   = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var TeamSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    users: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        }
    ]
});
TeamSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Team", TeamSchema);
```

And this is the seeding attempt:

```
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');

function seed(collectionName, data, schema){
    schema.remove({}, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(collectionName + ".remove: " + err);
        } else {
            console.log("All " + collectionName + " collection removed");

            data.forEach(function(dt){
                schema.create(dt, function(err, newData){
                    if(err){
                        console.log(collectionName + ".create: " + err);
                    } else {
                        console.log(collectionName + " added: " + newData.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}

function seedDB(){
    var userData        = require('./data/userData'),
        userSchema      = require('../../models/user');
    seed("User", userData, userSchema);

    var teamData        = require('./data/teamData'),
        teamSchema      = require('../../models/team');
    seed("Team", teamData, teamSchema);
};

module.exports = seedDB;
```

Yes, I tried to encapsulate the *seed* function, so I could use it in every collection I would possibly want to seed (in fact, I believe this is the problem).

userData:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        name: "Name1",
        username: "nickname1",
        password: "pass"
    },
    {
        name: "Name2",
        username: "nickname2",
        password: "pass"
    }
];
```

teamData:

```
module.exports = [
    {
        name: "Team1",
        users: [
            { "_id" : "594497aa0a403b183ce7e485", "name" : "Name1", "username" : "nickname1", "password" : "pass", "__v" : 0 },
            { "_id" : "594497aa0a403b183ce7e486", "name" : "Name2", "username" : "nickname2", "password" : "pass", "__v" : 0 }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Team 2",
        users: [
            { "_id" : "594497aa0a403b183ce7e485", "name" : "Name1", "username" : "nickname1", "password" : "pass", "__v" : 0 }
        ]
    }
];
```

When I run *seed()*, I get this error message:

```
Team.create: WriteError({"code":11000,"index":0,"errmsg":"E11000 duplicate key error collection: pastinha2.teams index: username_1 dup key: { : null }","op":{"name":"Team 2","_id":"5944afd68157e62190ec1919","users":["594497aa0a403b183ce7e485"],"__v":0}})
```

As far as I could understand, the problem is the order things are being executed, since the query calls are asynchronous. Not sure if this is really the issue, but if it is, how can I prevent it from happening?

Sorry for the long post, but I found several threads with similar problems, and I'm still really stuck here. Could use some help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I understand you put a unique key on `"username"` in the `"Users`" collection and you are actually trying to insert them **twice**. When you call [`.create()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.create) and specify the "full" related model data, then it tries to do exactly that and insert the same data for the "User" **twice**. Instead, populate the data to your "User" model separately. Then when doing your "Team", only include the `"_id"` **values** in the users array.

Comment: So just do this instead: `{ name: "Team1", users: ["594497aa0a403b183ce7e485", "594497aa0a403b183ce7e486"] }`. You do not need to pass in the whole object **twice**.

Comment: @NeilLunn Hi, there. Thanks for your answer.
I actually never set any unique keys in the Users collection. But I tried doing what you said anyway and it also didn't work. I, then, commented the population part of my Team Data, and I still got the error message.

Comment: Which makes me believe that the problem has nothing to do wih the relation of these collections.
Still stuck here =(

Comment: You have a unique index. This `index: username_1 dup key:` in the error response confirms it. Use `.dropIndexes()` on the collection to remove things you might have been playing around with at an earlier date.

Comment: Hi, @NeilLunn . Thanks for your help.
I've had already seen some threads saying that it could be some earlier statements that created indexes that aren't being used anymore. But every test I'm doing, I'm using db.collection.drop() in the mongo command line and then running my tests. And it's still not working.
Besides, when I use db.collection.getIndexes(), this index is never shown to me. Anyways, I tried the db.collection.dropIndexes() as well, and it also didn't work. x.x

Comment: I'm really confusing right now. I just got this strange behavior: I simplified my seed testing to just add data to the Team collection. There's no User collection anymore, nor associations and populations. Teams collections are very simple and straightforward. Running the app, sometimes it gets all done, with no errors, sometimes it gets the same error!!! (???)... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Seedgoose](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/seedgoose) instead. It supports smart references. In this case, it won't cause conflict error for you.